# $ P(XY \leq k)$ as integral of intersection

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

For two discreate random variables $X$ and $Y$, probability that $XY=k$ can be written as the sum of intersection as follows:

$ P(XY=k)= \sum_{t}P(X=t,Y=k/t)$

But if I apply the same method to continuous case, when $XY \leq k$, I think I'll get (not the equality)

$ P(XY \leq k) \leq \int_t P(X \leq t,Y \leq k/t)$

Am I right? How to write this transformation as integral of intersection? If I set $X$ = $t$ on the right side, I believe the integral will become zero which is not the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

No, for continuous random variable, you can't set $=$ sign, otherwise it becomes zero.

Assume $X\ge0, Y\ge0, k\ge 0$
$$P(XY\le k)=P(Y\le \frac{k}X)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{k/x} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy dx$$

Where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is the jointed probability density function.